# Simple WCF Publish Subscribe example

Tags: c#, wcf, networking

I want to have a service on which clients subscribes, and nothing more. The service will send about 300 times a second json data to all clients. Is that possible?

I would really appreciate any help.
Thanks in advance.

(P.S.: I am using C# and .Net 4.5)